# I have been making a React Native app, it works fine with no errors in Expo Go but it crashes in native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, crash, eas

The app works fine in Expo Go but when I make a simulator build on iOS and sideload it on to a device it crashes on the splash screen.

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [ip, setIp] = useState('');
  const [serial, setSerial] = useState('');
  const [ipInput, setIpInput] = useState('');
  const [serialInput, setSerialInput] = useState('');

  const fetchRequest = async (url) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      console.log('Request sent:', response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
  };

  const avec = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/assume_behavior_control?serial=${serial}`);
      await sleep(1000);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const rvec = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/release_behavior_control?serial=${serial}`);
      await sleep(1000);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const fw = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/move_wheels?lw=140&rw=140&serial=${serial}`);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const left = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/move_wheels?lw=-150&rw=150&serial=${serial}`);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const bc = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/move_wheels?lw=-150&rw=-150&serial=${serial}`);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const stop = async () => {
    if (ip && serial) {
      fetchRequest(`http://${ip}/api-sdk/move_wheels?lw=0&rw=0&serial=${serial}`);
    } else {
      console.error('IP or serial is missing.');
    }
  };

  const setIPAndSerial = () => {
    if (ipInput && serialInput) {
      setIp(ipInput);
      setSerial(serialInput);
    } else {
      console.error('Please enter IP and serial.');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Vector Control w/wirepod</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          label="Enter IP Address"
          placeholder="IP of wire-pod"
          value={ipInput}
          onChangeText={text => setIpInput(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          label="Enter Serial Number"
          placeholder="Serial of Vector"
          value={serialInput}
          onChangeText={text => setSerialInput(text)}
        />
        <Button title="Set IP and Serial" onPress={setIPAndSerial} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Assume Behaviour Control" onPress={avec} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Release Behaviour Control" onPress={rvec} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Move Forward" onPress={fw} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Move Left" onPress={left} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Move Back" onPress={bc} style={styles.button} />
        <Button title="Stop" onPress={stop} style={styles.button} />
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    width: '80%',
    marginTop: '40%', // Adjust the margin to move content down
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  input: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: '200 %',
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 8,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  button: {
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: '100%',
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    borderRadius: 5,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wire-pod",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^4.3.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "^7.9.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I built an iOS simulator build with EAS build the build suceeded and gave the the .app file which I converted into a .ipa file using the well-known method.